# Table values blank in JSF

Tags: jsf

JSF excerpt:

```
<h:dataTable border="1" cellspacing="10">
 <h:column>     
    <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="FirstEntry" />
 </h:column>

 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Product Name</f:facet>
    #{userBean.firstName}
 </h:column>

 <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
    #{userBean.email}
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Gives me this in html:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="10">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Order No</th>
   <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
   <th scope="col">Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

The table always comes as an empty table with headers and nothing in rows. According to JSF tutorials this should work. As you can see i have tried several options of putting values in table( using outputText, using a bean, tried typing some casual text without tags, putting the text in quotes, using value=). Everytime the outcome is same. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `value` attribute in your `h:datatable`

See for example MyFaces JSF implementation: https://myfaces.apache.org/core21/myfaces-impl/tagdoc/h_dataTable.html

> Attrivute name: **value**
>   Attribute type: **Object**
>
> An EL expression that specifies the data model that backs this table.
>
> The value referenced by the EL expression can be of any type.
>
> - A value of type DataModel is used directly.
> - Array-like parameters of type array-of-Object, java.util.List, java.sql.ResultSet or javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result are wrapped in a corresponding DataModel that knows how to iterate over the elements.
> - Other values are wrapped in a DataModel as a single row.
>
> Note in particular that unordered collections, eg Set are not
>   supported. Therefore if the value expression references such an object
>   then the table will be considered to contain just one element - the
>   collection itself.

P.S. If you don't have a collection of elements for your table why do you need `h:datatable`? You might as well use html.